# Add click event to TH pseudo element, get data attribute from TH and prevent TH event from firing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I am creating an HTML table which currently has a click event attached to the column heading `TH` to sort the table.

What I am now trying to do is to expand a column by showing additional hidden columns when you click "somewhere". 
Now, my initial thought for this "somewhere" was to create a `:pseudo` element on each `TH` which has hidden columns (they all have a specific css class) and to attach the show event on to this `:pseudo` element, however, when I do this its triggering the column sorting.

I have tried changing `$('.xxp').on('click', function () {`  to `$('.xxp:before').on('click', function () {` but I because the `TH` has data attributes that I need, when I use `$(this).parent('th')` I am not able to get the data so the expand is not firing.... Can you target the parent of a pseudo element?

So, looking at the snippet, I want to click on the green to sort the table, I want to click on the red to show the hidden columns but not trigger the sort at the same time (which it is currently).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var openData = null;
            $('.xxp').on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    colData = $this.data('col'),
                    openItem = $('.xx_' + colData + 'c'),
                    xplodeCols = $("td[class^='xx_'], th[class^='xx_']"),
                    moreInfoCols = $('.xMI_');

                //reset the columns
                xplodeCols.hide();

                //check if we are closing the current col
                if (openData == colData) {
                    //do something??
                    openData = null
                    moreInfoCols.show();
                }
                else {
                    openData = colData;
                    moreInfoCols.hide();
                    openItem.show();
                }
            });
        });

  //this is a dummy function for testing - 
  //I want the above code to run, but not this.
$('.xxp').on('click', function () {
 //   alert('Ooops! I did not want this event to fire!');
});
```

```css
table td, table th {border:1px solid #ccc; width:30px}   
td[class^='xx_'], th[class^='xx_'] {
        display: none;
    }
.xxp {background: #00ff00 !important;}
    th[class^='xx_'] {
        background: #ccc !important;
    }

    .xxp:before {
        display:inline-block;
        width:15px;
        height:15px;
        content:"";
        background-color:#ff0000;
        float:right;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:-20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br />
<table class="rpt">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th title="G" class="xxp" data-col="0">G</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.1</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.2</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.3</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.4</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.5</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.6</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.7</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.8</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.9</th>
      <th title="F" class="xxp" data-col="1">F</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.1</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.2</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.3</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.4</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.5</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.6</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.7</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.8</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.9</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td> 1</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">1</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td> 3</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">2</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">1</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0 </td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0 </td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0 </td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td>0 </td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td> 1</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">1</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">2</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/qkv510ot/

Comment: You cannot attach listeners to pseudo elements. They are dubbed *pseudo* for a reason…

Comment: yes @Bergi, I knew that they did not actually exist in the DOM. I was hoping that maybe a combination of `pointer-events` used on the `:before:hover` could be an option, but I would need to figure that out.

Comment: Rather create an actual element and append that to the `<th>`. I don't see a reason to use CSS pseude elements for this.

Comment: Ah, yes. thanks @Bergi I can't believe that I did not think of that. It's one of those days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the suggestion from @bergi this is how I did it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

             var pseudoBtn = $('<span />').attr({ 'class': 'pseudoBtn' });
             $('.xxp').prepend(pseudoBtn);

            var openData = null;
            $('.xxp span.pseudoBtn').on('click', function (e) {

                e.stopPropagation();
                var $this = $(this).parent('th'),
                    colData = $this.data('col'),
                    openItem = $('.xx_' + colData + 'c'),
                    xplodeCols = $("td[class^='xx_'], th[class^='xx_']"),
                    moreInfoCols = $('.xMI_');

                //reset the columns
                xplodeCols.hide();

                //check if we are closing the current col
                if (openData == colData) {
                    //do something??
                    openData = null
                    moreInfoCols.show();
                }
                else {
                    openData = colData;
                    moreInfoCols.hide();
                    openItem.show();
                }
            });
        });

  //this is a dummy function for testing - 
  //I want the above code to run, but not this.
$('.xxp').on('click', function () {
 //   alert('Ooops! I did not want this event to fire!');
});
```

```css
table td, table th {border:1px solid #ccc; width:30px}   
td[class^='xx_'], th[class^='xx_'] {
        display: none;
    }
.xxp {background: #00ff00 !important;}
    th[class^='xx_'] {
        background: #ccc !important;
    }

    .xxp > span.pseudoBtn {
        display:inline-block;
        width:15px;
        height:15px;
        background-color:#ff0000;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:-20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br />
<table class="rpt">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th title="G" class="xxp" data-col="0">G</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.1</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.2</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.3</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.4</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.5</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.6</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.7</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.8</th>
      <th title="G" class="xx_0c">.9</th>
      <th title="F" class="xxp" data-col="1">F</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.1</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.2</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.3</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.4</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.5</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.6</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.7</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.8</th>
      <th title="F" class="xx_1c">.9</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td> 1</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">1</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td> 3</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">2</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">1</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0 </td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0 </td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0 </td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td class="xx_0c"></td>
      <td>0 </td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
      <td class="xx_1c"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td> 1</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">1</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_0c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">2</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xx_1c">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```